# GDB and Python: How to disable Y/N requirement about running python as root

Tags: python, gdb

I'm running GDB with a bash(.sh) script that does need sudo/super user access and it works good, but there is a problem, every time i runs gdb with that script, before gdb load the executable it will ask about running python with superuser. I want to remove this requirement/question.

I want to remove this:

> WARNING: Phyton has been executed as super user! It is recommended to
>   run as a normal user. Continue? (y/N)

I'm using gdb 7.9 on ubuntu server 12.x which i compiled by my own.

Ps: In another ubuntu server(version 15) the gdb(version 7.9) will not ask this question using the same script and access.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that warning message is coming from a Tibia MMORPG server and not from gdb. If you don't run gdb, do you still get the error?

Comment: Oh, why you said its about a tibia mmorpg server?

Comment: I did a web search for the error message. If the error message came from gdb's Python  library, it would say its name is Python, not Phyton.

Comment: I did search, but it dindt show, this phyton/python thing trolled me so hard. Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Run gdb with the --batch command line option. This will disable all confirmation requests. You can also run the command "set confirm off"

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Both will not work, tried with --batch and set confirm off and still the same result:                                                                  WARNING: Phyton has been executed as super user! It is recommended to run as a normal user.
Continue? (y/N)

Comment: Could you post the entire line which is failing?

Comment: Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb:
gdb: warning:
Could not load the Python gdb module from `/usr/local/share/gdb/python'.
Limited Python support is available from the _gdb module.
Suggest passing --data-directory=/path/to/gdb/data-directory.

Catchpoint 1 (signals SIGBUS SIGFPE SIGILL SIGINT SIGSEGV SIGSYS SIGSYS SIGXCPU SIGXFSZ)
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
> WARNING: Phyton has been executed as super user! It is recommended to run as a normal user.
Continue? (y/N)

Comment: I want to remove this y/N cofirmation.

Comment: I would go look at this [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597445/python-exception-type-exceptions-importerror-no-module-named-gdb) and see if that helps.Otherwise you could try "echo 'y' | command which is failing"

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the python loading issue, but its still asking (y/N)

Comment: I have found the issue, it was on the software i was using, it was not related to gdb. Thanks bro :)