# gdb cannot load Python

Tags: macos, gdb, gdb-python

I get this warning/error message when launching gdb. It disabled some features. Anyone has a fixed? Thanks.

`Could not load the Python gdb module from`/usr/local/share/gdb/python'.`

Comment: Did you build gdb from source? See related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/25597445/72178.

Comment: yes  I did. The thing is I usually use Linux for debugging so I can use gdb-dashboard but my mac is running slow lately, so I wanted to do that on my mac without launching  a VM. I read somewhere that I have to tell gdb where to the python module but can't seem to work even after removing all python and gdb residues and reinstalling them.