# Unable to use eclipse CDT to debug

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-mars

I am using eclipse mars to try to debug an application. When I use Run->Debug

The console shows following error message:

```
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb: 
gdb: warning: 
Could not load the Python gdb module from `/usr/local/share/gdb/python'.
Limited Python support is available from the _gdb module.
Suggest passing --data-directory=/path/to/gdb/data-directory.
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597445/python-exception-type-exceptions-importerror-no-module-named-gdb/25601632) mentioned a way might fix the problem but I can not find where should I put the `./gdb -data-directory ./data-directory` in eclipse.

Thanks

Rong

Comment: A common cause of this error is when you compile gdb from source but, rather than doing `make install` to install it, just copy gdb into `/usr/local/bin` but don't copy any of the auxiliary data files that go along with it. Do you still have the source code used to build gdb?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I do not have the gdb source, since I did that a while ago, I guess I could download the latest gdb and rebuild again, right?

Comment: Yes, you can always rebuild it.

Comment: Debugger TAB in eclipse mentions GDB command file (which is .gdbinit in your home by default). You can but "set data-directory <some-path>" there.